# Calling setZoom in webextension page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a `New tab` replacement for browsers and **I want to reset zoom level in certain situations for my page**. It works in Firefox but in Chrome it seems to be blocked by security policy:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.setZoom: Cannot access a chrome:// URL
```

Using this code inside script in my page:

```
chrome.tabs.setZoom(1, () => {})
```

I know accessing `chrome://` is restricted but this should work for my own extension, right?
Is there a way to fix this (or some workaround)?

[setZoom() documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-setZoom)

EDIT:
After more testing, this will work if I manually set full URL like:

```
chrome-extension://onbnheemmeialopoekmofndfmbkpdmbl/dial.html?
```

See the questionmark at the end, without it the URL bar will be empty since this is a `New tab` replacement. Then it won't work anymore.

Comment: Seems like chrome extension API developers overlooked this use case. Care to report on https://crbug.com if it wasn't already reported? Also, consider using CSS `zoom` property on `html` element.

Comment: Thanks, [reported here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696155). Regarding `zoom` property, actually I want to avoid zoom and best prevent user to zoom. I know this doesn't sounds good, but zooming is also not very useful in my webextension, but it greatly complicates some of the computations I do... Maybe with a cup of coffee in the morning right after long vacation I will be able to do the correct math :)